# How to move the marker(current marker) on google map as Device moves in android

Tags: android, android-maps

how to moves marker(like dot) on google map as device moves (user moves).....

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay;

// This class subclasses (extends) MyLocationOverlay so that we can override its dispatchTap method
// to handle tap events on the present location dot.

public class MyMyLocationOverlay extends MyLocationOverlay {

private Context context;

public MyMyLocationOverlay(Context context, MapView mapView) {
    super(context, mapView);
    this.context = context;   // Will need this for Toast argument below
}

// Override the dispatchTap() method to toggle the data display on and off when
// the present location dot is tapped. Also display a short Toast (transient message) to the
// user indicating the display status change.

@Override
protected boolean dispatchTap(){
    if(DisplayOverlay.showData){ 
        Toast.makeText(context, "Suppressing data readout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context,"Display data readout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    // Toggle the GPS data display
    DisplayOverlay.showData = ! DisplayOverlay.showData;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

check my post answer there was link.

[how to display map in android with marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140433/how-to-display-map-in-android-with-marker/7189925#7189925)

for moving marker on map you need to create the static method in the your class which extends the MapActivity like

```
private static GeoPoint markerPoint;

public static void updateLocation(Location location){
   lat = location.getLatitude();
   lng = location.getLongitude();

   // now use this lat/lng value to convert into the GeoPoint object

   markerPoint = new GeoPoint(lat * 1e6, lng * 1e6);
   mapview.invalidate();
}
```

your custom overlay class which extends the Overlay class.

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean Shadow){
    Point screenPts = new Point();
    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(markerPoint, screenPts);
    //---add the marker---
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cur_loc_1);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x-(xCurLocOffset), screenPts.y-yCurLocOffset, null);
}
```

here to display your drawable image display using Bitmap class to draw image on map.

Comment: Hi, Why you subtracted xCurLocaOffset & yCurLocaOffset from screenPts x&y coordinate? I have used the same thing but not subtracted xCurLocaOffset & yCurLocaOffset in code and the Bitmap is drawn but not at the exact location but it is slightly right. Why so? can you please help

Comment: I have subtracted the Bitmap x and y offset to place the marker on perfect location. It's depends on ur Image/Drawable which you have display as marker