# android gps how to display current position

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm not well experienced in android development and I want to display my current position on a map. But it shows me a different location, which is in canada. Here is my code:

```
package com.manita.mapuse;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;

import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
public class MapuseActivity extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {
    private MapView  mapView = null;
    private MapController mc;
    private GeoPoint location;
    double lat;
    double lon;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

      //---use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations---
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    

        LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

        lm.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,  0, 0, locationListener);

        }


    /* Class My Location Listener */

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener

    {

    @Override

    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)

    {

    loc.getLatitude();

    loc.getLongitude();

    lat= loc.getLatitude();

    lon= loc.getLongitude();
    }

    @Override

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)

    {

    }


    @Override

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)

    {
    }


    @Override

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)

    {


    }

    } /*End of Class MyLocationListener */





    /*   class map view     */

    public MapView viewmap (View mapview, double latitude, double longitude){

        this.mapView =  new MapView(this,this.getResources().getString(R.string.mapKey));

        this.mapView.setClickable(true);

        this.mc = this.mapView.getController();

        this.location = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1000000.0),(int) (longitude * 1000000.0));

        this.mc.setCenter(this.location);

        this.mc.setZoom(17);

        this.mapView.setSatellite(true);

        this.mapView.invalidate();

        this.setContentView(this.mapView);

        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        return mapView;

    }
     /* End class map view     */



    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html#overview_maps
is a very nice example. Just copy paste and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I too much confuse you need to many change in this try to check out some tutorial from my post you getting many links from there

[how to display map in android with marker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6140433/760489)

Answer (score 0):

Is this all the code?  I don't see any calls to your mapview object to update the latitude or longitude.  Maybe try initing the mc controller and adding in this bit of code to the onLocationChanged method and see what happens.  This is just to help you find the issue, don't actually leave the code like this because it is dangerous to utilize the MapController if you don't even know if it has been inited or not yet.

```
@Override

public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)

{
  loc.getLatitude();
  loc.getLongitude();
  lat= loc.getLatitude();
  lon= loc.getLongitude();
  this.location = new GeoPoint((int) (latitude * 1000000.0),(int) (longitude * 1000000.0));
  this.mc.setCenter(this.location);
}
```