# add marker image using paint on mapview

Tags: android, android-maps, android-view

I have added multiple ovals on map view by using below code but I want to add bubble mark image (or any any marker) how I can use image in this case.
in overlay class:

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
    try{
        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        // Create and setup your paint brush
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setARGB(250, 255, 0, 0);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFakeBoldText(true);

        if (shadow == false) {
            for (GeoPoint point : array_Locations) {
                Point myPoint = new Point();
                projection.toPixels(point, myPoint);
                RectF oval = new RectF(myPoint.x-rad, 
                                 myPoint.y-rad, myPoint.x+rad, myPoint.y+rad);
                canvas.drawOval(oval, paint);
                canvas.drawText( "place of interest", myPoint.x, myPoint.y, paint);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.toString();
    }
```

in map activity :

```
mapView.getOverlays().add(new HelloItemizedOverlay(cursor));
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Comment: check my post http://stackoverflow.com/q/6140433/760489

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding bubble in onDraw() you can do it in your overlay class constructor (in your case HelloItemizedOverlay).

For example see code from here [MapView with balloons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons).