# Best Way to Add Map Pins to Google Map Android

Tags: android, android-maps

I have been successful at adding the pins but I need the pins to be refreshed when the user clicks on the map and provides a new location, I get an error. Keep in mind that I need this to happen in the background so that it does not affect the map interaction.

My problem is that when the user clicks on the map the list of map pins is already being updated and I get an `ConcurrentModificationException` error.

Basically, I have a `JSONArray` which has locations. I need each location to be on the map and when the new location is touched the pins are updated and the old pins are cleared.

Any suggestions on how to make this more friendly and easier. I cannot seem to get rid of the `ConcurrentModificationException` error.

Comment: check my post http://stackoverflow.com/q/6140433/760489

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the "the missing widget"...

[image]

- Balloons without icons: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons#readme
- Balloons with icons (extends Jeff Gilfelt's project): https://github.com/galex/android-mapviewballoons

Comment: I know how to add the map pins to the map. The problem I have is that the `JSONArray` I have is being ran through a background thread which is then ran through a for loop. The problem is each time the map is touched it starts the `ASYNCTask` while the old `ASYNCTask` is still running through the for loop. I need to either have the old `ASYNCTask` canceled when the user touches the map or wait for the map list to finish updating.

Comment: Balloons with icons link is broken