# Android: How to add pin to google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best Way to Add Map Pins to Google Map Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641465/best-way-to-add-map-pins-to-google-map-android)

How to add pin and if clicked show balon with info address or city which I have custom getOverlay()  in google maps API android.

Below my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_map);

    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    GeoPoint gpStart = new GeoPoint((int) (-6.31689 * 1E6),
            (int) (106.74040 * 1E6));

    GeoPoint gpEnd = new GeoPoint((int) (-6.29729 * 1E6),
            (int) (106.78386 * 1E6));

    Route r = direction(gpStart, gpEnd);
    RouteOverlay rOverlay = new RouteOverlay(r, Color.RED);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(rOverlay);
    mapView.getController().animateTo(gpStart);
    mapView.getController().setZoom(15);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
}
```

My code have edited, Code in above i get from [here](http://swarawan.com/android/android-google-maps-api-menggunakan-json/) and work for me, but not show pin on location. I know to put pin wich if code is standart from google maps V1. Just add overlay. But my problem is I get map from json array. So i want to add pin in location(geopoint) and if i click i get info address.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Google Maps API are you using? v2?

Comment: V1 not V2. If V2 i know.

Comment: I have edit my post Mr Avadhani

Comment: Then you should upgrade to V2 soon. API V1 will not support new applications any more.

Comment: If I use api V2, I cannot implement route path by driving. Before I use V2 there I get pin and ballon if i click. Now i'm using V1 and get path route but not get pin :-). Here my problem when i use V2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515330/android-how-to-get-direction-route-driving-between-two-location-with-google-map/14516121

Answer (score 12):

If you're using the [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/), which you should do, it's [documented here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker).

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
    .title("Hello world"));
```