# Android OnItemCLickListener not working in listview

Tags: android, google-maps, android-listview, onclicklistener

I am new to android programming.I am developing an app in which when user clicks on any ListView item it should go to Google maps app and display pin for that address on the map. But when I click on any item nothing happens.
Following is my display Activity.

```
public class DisplayActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

ListView listView;
private String tag_name; 
public List<NameAddress> nameAddressList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent!= null)
    {
        tag_name = intent.getStringExtra("DashItemName");
        setTitle("List of " +tag_name+ " addresses");
    }

    nameAddressList = null;
    try {
            XMLDOMParserHandler parser = new XMLDOMParserHandler(tag_name);
        nameAddressList = parser.parseXML(getAssets().open("data.xml"));
        ArrayAdapter<NameAddress> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<NameAddress>(this,R.layout.list_item, nameAddressList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    // Build the intent
    String address = nameAddressList.get(position).toString();
    address = "geo:0,0?q=" + address;
    String query = URLEncoder.encode(address, "utf-8");
    Uri location = Uri.parse(query);
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, location;
    mapIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");

    // Verify it resolves
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(mapIntent, 0);
    boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;

    // Start an activity if it's safe
    if (isIntentSafe) {
        startActivity(mapIntent);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install google maps app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

} 

}
```

Please suggest me a way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Please suggest me a way to solve this problem.

It doesn't work for you because you forgot to assign listener to ListView:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    ...
}
```

Now, it will work for you.

Comment: I tried it but it is giving following Error: "the method setOnOnClickListener(View.OnClickListner) in the type AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for arguments(DisplayActivity)"

Comment: @Akshay not OnClickListener but **OnItemClickListener**!

Comment: Now it is showing map but not showing address on it(i.e. pin for given address)

Comment: @Akshay so this is i think another question that is not related to listener for ListView. Have look at [how to display map in android with marker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140433/how-to-display-map-in-android-with-marker).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the listener to your ListView.
Just after  the creation of listView you should add:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    //your onItemClick code

    }
}
```